# Regular Expression to Capture for Number within Quotes and with/out Space

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression that will capture any string literal that starts with JKB and the number following it.

I have the following Reg Ex built for it:

```
(?'Account'JKB[0-9]+LC),(?'Amount'[0-9,.]*)
```

It captures the `Amount` in all except the first and second from the following list:

1. 29/7/2021,FDC Bank PLC / Mr P.S.R STEVE SMITH,JKB99999LC," 9,500,000 "
2. 29/7/2021,FDC Bank PLC / Mr P.S.R STEVE SMITH,JKB99999LC,"9,500,000"
3. 29/7/2021,FDC Bank PLC / Mr P.S.R STEVE SMITH,JKB99999LC,9500000
4. 29/7/2021,FDC Bank PLC / Mr P.S.R STEVE SMITH,JKB99999LC,9,500,000

How can I make my RegEx accommodate to capture 1st and 2nd item too; at least the number

Here is my working: https://regex101.com/r/mcQtA9/2

Comment: @SebastianSchumann Your demo doesn't capture all `Amount` group. However, the answer from @wiktor-Stribiżew below does

Comment: Oh - sorry. Misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assure the substring between the two group patterns is consumed. You can use

```cs
(?<Account>JKB[0-9]+LC),"?\s*(?<Amount>[0-9,.]*)
(?<Account>JKB[0-9]+LC),\W*(?<Amount>[0-9,.]*)
```

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mcQtA9/5) and the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3CAccount%3EJKB%5B0-9%5D%2BLC%29%2C%22%3F%5Cs*%28%3F%3CAmount%3E%5B0-9%2C.%5D*%29&i=29%2F7%2F2021%2CFDC%20Bank%20PLC%20%2F%20Mr%20P.S.R%20STEVE%20SMITH%2CJKB99999LC%2C%22%209%2C500%2C000%20%22%0D%0A29%2F7%2F2021%2CFDC%20Bank%20PLC%20%2F%20Mr%20P.S.R%20STEVE%20SMITH%2CJKB99999LC%2C%229%2C500%2C000%22%0D%0A29%2F7%2F2021%2CFDC%20Bank%20PLC%20%2F%20Mr%20P.S.R%20STEVE%20SMITH%2CJKB99999LC%2C9500000%0D%0A29%2F7%2F2021%2CFDC%20Bank%20PLC%20%2F%20Mr%20P.S.R%20STEVE%20SMITH%2CJKB99999LC%2C9%2C500%2C000%0D%0As):

[image]

I used `"?\s*` in the first pattern to match an optional `"` and then zero or more whitespace chars. In the second variation, I just used `\W*` to match any zero or more non-word chars.

I prefer `(?<name>...)` named capturing group syntax, but you may use single quoted variant, if you are more accustomed to that syntax.

Comment: Noted that your 2nd `RegEx` listed above `(?<Account>JKB[0-9]+LC),"W*(?<Amount>[0-9,.]*)` is incorrect; Shouldn't it be `(?<Account>JKB[0-9]+LC),"?\W*(?<Amount>[0-9,.]*)` ? That too captures all.

Comment: @hiFI We can only speak about a regex "correctness" when we have exact specs. In this case, `,\W*` will work the same way as `,"?\W*` as `"` is a non-word char.